# Generating accessor method in java code generated from WSDL

Tags: java, wsdl, code-generation

I am generating a java web service from a WSDL 1.1 document.  I'm using Netbeans.  The service generates fine and I can deploy it to Tomcat with no problem.

Now, I have a type for my response called "searchPhoneOutputType".  When it generates, the class contains a method called List getOutput(), which allows me to get the list of results.

My question is the following, how could I tell the code generator to also generate a setOutput(List out) method?  I could do it by hand, but then it would get overwritten when I re-generate code.

I'm wondering if there is some type of annotation XML I can use to tell the code generator to generate certain methods.

If you could shed some light I would greatly appreciate it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how Netbeans generates these bindings, must be via JAXB.
Hence we have the .jxb config files, where you can put in generation instructions.

Extensive doc: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html